# Connecting to MySql on Docker

Tags: mysql, asp.net-web-api, docker, asp.net-core, dnx

I have an ASP.NET 5 Web API application which I have deployed on docker. It connects to a MySql instance, also on docker. I am using Entity Framework 6 to connect to the MySql database. I have not referenced Entity Framework directly, but am using the MySql.Data.Entity package which internally uses Entity Framework 6.

When I invoke the API, I get this error:

Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory'

Outside docker, i.e., on my windows machine, in Visual Studio 2015, I point my web API to the MySql instance on docker, and I can connect just fine. Inside docker, I get the error mentioned above.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The provider name is not being passed.  Prior to ASP.NET 5 the `provider` value could be set alongside `connectionString` in in the web.config.  This is no longer the case, as the connection string is just a string value in a json file with no extra properties.

You need to set it programatically.  [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31767626/469777), notably this part;

```
SetProviderServices("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new MySqlProviderServices());
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the correct answer. In my case, I had a separate configuration class, like so:

public class MyDbConfiguration : DbConfiguration

I changed that to 

public classs MyDbConfiguration : MySqlEFConfiguration, and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert on ASP.NET, but doesn't your question translate to:

> If I run ASP.NET on Windows everything works fine, if I run it on
>   Linux I get an exception.

?

I don't think this is a Docker issue and would rather investigate about issues / driver needs the Entity Framework has on Mono.

Comment: Good point. I found the solution when I changed my line of investigation along the lines you mentioned. Thank you. I have accepted Stafford Williams' answer.